# Writing cpp file from existing header file to run test program. errors present

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, testing, header

I'm trying to write a .cpp file from an existing .h file. I am getting some errors.  Any feedback is appreciated on how to get this running. im kinda new at this and I've been watching the videos and writing off of existing files, but something isn't right.

here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<string>
#include"quad.h"

using namespace std;


//--constructor (no default constructor for quadraticEquation)
  quadraticEquation::quadraticEquation(double initA, double initB, double initC)
// post: initialize coefficients of quadratic equation initA*x*x + initB + c
  {
  my_a=initA;
  my_b=initB;
  my_c=initC;

  }

//--accessors  
  double quadraticEquation::root1() const
  // pre: there is at least one real root: b*b-4*a*c >= 0.0 
  // post: returns one real root as  (-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)) / (2*a)
  {
      (my_b+sqrt(my_b*my_b-4*my_a*my_c))/(2*my_a);
  }

  double quadraticEquation::root2() const
  // pre: there is at least one real root: b*b-4*a*c >= 0.0 
  // post: returns one real root as  (-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)) / (2*a)
  { (my_b-sqrt(my_b*my_b-4*my_a*my_c))/(2*my_a);
  }

  bool quadraticEquation::hasRealRoots() const
  // post: returns true if an only if b*b-4*a*c >= 0.0, otherwise return false

  { if (my_b*my_b-4*my_a*my_c >= 0.0);
  }

  void quadraticEquation::display() const
  // post: shows the quadratic equation like -1x^2 + 3x - 9.7
  //       when my_a == -1, my_b = 3, and my_c == -9.7

  {
      cout << my_a << "x^2";


  if(my_b >= 0)
  cout << " + " << my_b << "x";
      else
  cout << " - " << abs(my_b) << "x";
 if(my_c >= 0)
  cout << " + " << my_c;
      else
  cout << " - " << abs(my_c);

  }


private:
  double my_a, my_b, my_c; // the three coefficients of the quadratic equation
};
```

Here are my errors:

```
cpp(24): warning C4552: '/' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
cpp(30): warning C4552: '/' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
error C2059: syntax error : 'private'
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
 error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your errors, it is clear that there are basic syntax errors in the code. You should particularly pay attention when your compiler explicitly says:

```
warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
```

It is also encouraged to put curly braces in your function, so your display function can be cleaned up to look something like this:

```
void quadraticEquation::display() const
{
   cout << my_a << "x^2";
   if(my_b >= 0)
     { cout << " + " << my_b << "x"; }
   else
     { cout << " - " << abs(my_b) << "x"; }

   if(my_c >= 0)
     { cout << " + " << my_c; }
   else
     { cout << " - " << abs(my_c); }
}
```

The compiler errors can be really informative - it gives you line numbers, and for basic issues like "missing ;" or "expected {, found (" means that there's a minor typo somewhere. Double check your code blocks - are they aligned properly?

Comment: ok, thanks @pixeld.  what about error C2059: syntax error : 'private'

Comment: turns out i didnt need that! :)  thanks for the help! @user2438619

Comment: The reason you didn't need to write private is because all variables declared within a class is private by default :) [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)